# Drawing circles and arrows using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to plot two circles one below the other. I also want two draw two arrows (I prefer solid curly arrows) between the circles.

So far I tried the below code, but it is not working.  Can anyone help ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\tikzstyle{circ} = [circle, minimum size=1cm, text centered, draw = black, fill = red!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{block}{Model}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
    \node (env) [circ] {Environment};
    \node (agent) [circ, below of=env] {Agent};
    \draw [arrow] (env) -- (agent);
    \draw [arrow] (agent) -- (env);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Increasing the `node distance`, for example to 4cm, isn't enough?

Comment: That is, you want a depth effect as if one circle were behind the other?

Comment: I want two arrows between the circles (one from env to agent and other from agent to env). Also, if possible I want the arrows to be solid and curvy.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you looking for this:

[image]

- For above image I employ TikZ library `positioning` and use its syntax `below=of env` (observe difference in order of `=` and `of`).  With this the `node distance` define distance between nodes borders.
- As you define distance between nodes (without using `positioning` library), `node distance` define distance between center of circles. So in your case it should be increased significantly (considering size of nodes' shapes)
- Regarding arrows, for it is used `bend left` option for edges. If you like to have bend more curved than the picture above shows, than just add angle to bend, for example `bend left=45`:
- Further costumization of styles I left to you. You can ease to change thickens of arrows and shape borders, their colors, size of text etc.
- Note, use of `\tikzstyle{...} = [...]` s deprecated. Instead of it is recommended to use `\tikzset{ ... }` or define styles as options of `tikzpicture` as is done in MWE below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                positioning}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{block}{Model}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1cm,
      circ/.style = {circle, draw, fill = red!30,
                     minimum size=1cm, align=center},
every edge/.style = {draw, very thick, -Stealth, bend left}
                        ]
    \node (env)   [circ] {Environment};
    \node (agent) [circ, below=of env] {Agent};
    \draw   (env)   edge[bend left] (agent)
            (agent) edge[bend left] (env);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```